# Meta Descriptions - Item Count Appearing on Search Engines

Tags: category, category-tree, category-products, meta-tags, items

For category pages, when displayed on search engines, there is an "item count" that is displayed before the meta description.  I fear this may be hurting our click through rates.

Is there a way to disable this?

Is there a reason not to?

I've included a screenshot of Google results below.

[image]

Comment: For better context to everyone, could you post a screenshot or more details about how the item count is displayed?

Comment: If you click "edit" to update your question, then in the content editor box, you can press `Ctrl + G` or else click the _picture_ toolbar icon to upload an picture. It even supports image pasting on most browsers.

Comment: Added a screenshot.  If you type "Jovani" which is one of our manufacturers, the item count comes up before the meta description.  This happens for all category pages.  Most of our traffic comes from organic traffic to these catalog pages, so I worry that it may affect our click through rate.

Answer (score 2):

These types of information, in the case of Google Search, are called Rich Snippets:

**About Rich Snippets & Structured Data**

> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en

Upon running that particular page returned by the query `Jovani` through the Google *Structured Data Testing Tool*:

**Google Structured Data Testing Tool**

> https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

I get results which indicate that someone has implemented [Microdata](http://www.schema.org/) for one or more areas of your site. However, I find no microdata that explains why you have the pager item count appearing in search results. It seems to me that this is another case of Google automatically determining what's considered microdata:

> http://searchengineland.com/from-microdata-schema-to-rich-snippets-markup-for-the-advanced-seo-162902#comment-934655397

The above is just one example of people talking about the random ocurrence, although I've heard several complaints personally. I don't think there's a clear answer. If you're not adding microdata to reference the pager details, then it shouldn't be used by the search engine.

If you can, ask the developers of your site if microdata has been employed in a way that I can't tell from my perspective, or consider submitting a ticket to [Google's product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/webmasters/structured-data) about it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I will try the Google product forums.  I've noticed it on another Magento store as well, I'm assuming it's default.

Comment: You're welcome. If possible, keep this question up to date with what you find, for both my sake and others who also have the same trouble.